# Show configuration of Docker container

Tags: docker, configuration, containers

So, I ran a docker image with certain settings a while ago. In the meantime I updated my container settings via "docker update".

Now I want to see, what options/configurations (e.g. cpuset, stack, swap) are currently configured for my container.

Is there a docker command to check this? 
If not, (why the hell isn't there and) where exactly can I find this information?

I am running docker 18.03.1-ce on debian 9.4.

Greetings,
Johannes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get detailed information about containers settings one can use the `docker inspect` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/):

```bash
docker inspect [OPTIONS] NAME|ID [NAME|ID...]
```